# tensorflow lite on arduino nano 33 ble: Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'SHAPE' version '1'

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, tensorflow-lite

I used Tensorflow lite 2.1.0-ALPHA-PRECOMPILED for arduino nano 33 ble with headers.

Model Definition

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16,activation='relu', input_shape=(seq_len,12,1)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Model Summary

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 100, 12, 16)       32        
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 100, 12, 16)       272       
                                                                 
 dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 100, 12, 1)        17        
                                                                 
 flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 1200)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_7 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 1201      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,522
Trainable params: 1,522
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

and I converted to tflite

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

tflite_model = converter.convert()

open('saved_model/ver4.tflite','wb').write(tflite_model)
```

and I included in arduino

```
static tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<2> micro_op_resolver;  // NOLINT
micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(tflite::BuiltinOperator_FULLY_CONNECTED,
                              tflite::ops::micro::Register_FULLY_CONNECTED());
micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(tflite::BuiltinOperator_RESHAPE,
                              tflite::ops::micro::Register_RESHAPE());
```

in this case i get a error:

```
Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'SHAPE' version '1'

Failed to get registration from op code SHAPE
 
Failed starting model allocation.
```

I tried to include

```
micro_op_resolver.AddBuiltin(tflite::BuiltinOperator_SHAPE,
                              tflite::ops::micro::Register_SHAPE());
```

but got error message

```
Compilation error: 'Register_SHAPE' is not a member of 'tflite::ops::micro'
```

and I also tried

```
static tflite::AllOpsResolver resolver;
```

but didn't work either.

```
Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'SHAPE' version '1'

Failed to get registration from op code SHAPE
 
Failed starting model allocation.
```

like this

Answer (score 0):

this happens when there is a version mismatch between the tensorflow version you are using and the tflite micro inference engine. I'm not sure exactly which version of tensorflow lite for microcontrollers you are using, but it sounds out of date.